# Navigation Problem when go back using context api with react and material ui

Tags: reactjs, navigation, material-ui, react-navigation, react-context

I'm building a website with navigation on the header. I'm using context API for managing the navigation state. It all works fine but when I go back it does not update the state and does not update the active tab if I click on the tabs then it will update the state and active tab. Help me, please
Here is the GitHub link to my project
https://github.com/M-Afzaal-Afzal/Website-with-material-ui-and-react

Comment: Can you please provide a working example

Comment: i opened wesite the active tab is home tab. Then i clicked on about us in navigation , so about is active tab now. but if i go back the active tab is still about us... it is not going back to the home as active tab.